# How come I can't type anything into my React search box?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component called `SearchInput` and it has in it

```
  <input
    type='text'
    className='input-field'
    value={value}
    placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
    // onFocus={::this.onFocus}
    // onBlur={::this.onBlur}
    // onKeyUp={::this.onKeyUp}
    // onKeyDown={::this.hanleArrowKeys}
    // onChange={::this.onChange}
  />
```

However, when I type anything into it, nothing happens. The text doesn't even appear. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your state is not updating, maybe didn't you bind "this" to function onChange?

Here is an example of correct input in react:

```
class SearchInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '' };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are binding the value of the input box with an attribute in the state of the component and you are either not providing an onChange prop to the input tag or your onChange callback method is not updating the attribute in the state to which the input tag's value is bound.

Comment: onChange does not work for me. Could you please have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658623/unable-to-type-in-formik-field